# Looking for a library to perform gaussian curve fitting

Tags: c++

I'm looking for an easy-to-use and accurate C++ library or source code to perform gaussian curve fitting. I found `gsl`, `dlib` and other similar libraries very difficult to start with because this is one-time task and won't be going into such computing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with [MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/), a really good library for plotting, fitting and other good stuff. [Here](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/docs_v1/mathgl_en_9.html#Fitting-sample) is listing of code samples which really helped me.